# 504 Gateway Time-out- with scrapy-proxy-pool and scrapy-user-agents

Tags: python, scrapy

I am unable to crawl data, it shows 504 Gatway timeout error,
I tried using the bypass method UserAgent and Proxy Both but does not help me to crawl data.

I tried **scrapy-proxy-pool** for proxy method and **scrapy-user-agents** for useragetn method but both method does not work.

getting 504 Gateway Time-out

**my scrappy**

```
import scrapy
import time 
import random
class LaughfactorySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403, 504]
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["mywebsitewebsite"]

    def parse(self,response):
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,4))
        for site in response.xpath("//section[@class='test']/div/ul"):
            item = {
                'name': site.xpath("//li[@class='centr']//h2/span/text()").extract_first()
            }
            yield item
```

**settings.py**

```
###### For Dynamic Proxy

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'formsubmit_getresult.pipelines.FormsubmitGetresultPipeline': 300,
}
# To Enable Proxy
PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    # ...
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
    # ...
}

####### For Dynamic USerAgent Middleware
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly setting the `User-Agent` header that's why website is giving you 504. You need to add `User-Agent` header in the first request and all the subsequent requests.

Try something like this:

```
class LaughfactorySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403, 504]
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["mywebsitewebsite"]

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.start_urls[0], headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self,response):
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,4))
        for site in response.xpath("//section[@class='test']/div/ul"):
            item = {
                'name': site.xpath("//li[@class='centr']//h2/span/text()").extract_first()
            }
            yield item
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but i have used "scrapy-user-agents" middleware i think which does the same thing. you above solution is not working at my end.

Comment: It may be possible that other packages are interfering with this. Can you revert your settings and middlewares and then try this.

Comment: still same result